# Insert columns in the first place of a double entry table in python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, insert

So I got the table I wanted modifying my dataframe with `df.pivot_table()` and I got something like this:

[Dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1hzyi.png)

But now I want to relate those stations to their latitude and longitude value. Those are columns I have in a different dataframe and I thought a good way to do that would be placing those variables before the station column (latlon) in this dataframe.

I tried using `df.insert()`but giving it loc=0 deletes my dataframe.

Is there any way to do this? Or should I relate them through indexing or something like that? Maybe there's a simpler way to visualize what I want in my mind but I have no idea.

```
Date    2009-01-01 00:00:00     2009-01-02 00:00:00     2009-01-03 00:00:00
latlon                                                                                  
321332106443701     20.40   20.33   20.30   
321332106443703     19.17   19.16   19.16   
321540110205501     10.99   10.97   10.98   
321540110205502     10.00   9.99    9.99
```

And I what I want to add would be:

`latdeg londeg
32.225583   -64.736139
32.225583   -64.736139
32.225583   -64.736139
32.225583   -64.736139`

**Update:** I got the first table from a dataset using: 
`df = old_df.pivot_table('DepthBLS', ['latlon'], 'Date')`

So my problem was also solved by making this from the beginning: 
`df = old_df.pivot_table('DepthBLS', ['latlon','latdeg','londeg'], 'Date')`

and no need to reindex. Sorry now I see it was kind of silly! But the reply I got was very useful in case i have a double entry table and no original data to work with.

Comment: welcome to stackoverflow! Could you copy and paste some rows of your dataframe to work with it

Comment: I kind of found out how to paste some rows in the original post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regarding the error you get with `df.insert()`, the function has no return (i.e. returns `None`), and if you assign the dataframe using `df = df.insert(...)`, this could be the source of the issue. Instead leave out the assignment and just use `df.insert(...)`.

If you still have issues, there are other ways to achieve this. If you have the `latdeg` and `londeg` columns in a separate dataframe which aligns with this one, you can add them using the following (where `latlondf` is your second dataframe, using `.values` to ignore the indexes):

```
df['latdeg'] = latlondf['latdeg'].values
df['londeg'] = latlondf['londeg'].values
```

By default, these columns will appear to the right of your dataframe, but you can bring them to the left of the frame using `df.reindex()`:

```
df = df.reindex(
    columns=["latdeg", "londeg"]
    + [i for i in df.columns if i not in ["latdeg", "londeg"]]
)
```

Replicating your dataframes and expanding some:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# replicate the dataframes

df = pd.DataFrame(
    [
        [20.40, 20.33, 20.30],
        [19.17, 19.16, 19.1],
        [10.99, 10.97, 10.98],
        [10.00, 9.99, 9.99],
    ],
    columns=["2009-01-01 00:00:00", "2009-01-02 00:00:00", "2009-01-03 00:00:00"],
    index=[321332106443701, 321332106443703, 321540110205501, 321540110205502],
)

latlondf = pd.DataFrame(
    [
        [32.225583, -64.736139],
        [32.225583, -64.736139],
        [32.225583, -64.736139],
        [32.225583, -64.736139],
    ],
    columns=["latdeg", "londeg"],
)

df.columns.name = "Date"
df.index.name = "latlon"

# Options 1: insert

df.insert(0, "latdeg", latlondf["latdeg"].values)
df.insert(1, "londeg", latlondf["londeg"].values)

# Option 2 - assign and reindex
df["latdeg"] = latlondf["latdeg"].values
df["londeg"] = latlondf["londeg"].values


df = df.reindex(
    columns=["latdeg", "londeg"]
    + [i for i in df.columns if i not in ["latdeg", "londeg"]]
)

# check output

df
```

```
Date    latdeg  londeg  2009-01-01 00:00:00 2009-01-02 00:00:00 2009-01-03 00:00:00
latlon                  
321332106443701 32.225583   -64.736139  20.40   20.33   20.30
321332106443703 32.225583   -64.736139  19.17   19.16   19.10
321540110205501 32.225583   -64.736139  10.99   10.97   10.98
321540110205502 32.225583   -64.736139  10.00   9.99    9.99
```

Comment: You were totally right, I left out the assignment by just using df.insert(...) and it worked! Thank you! Now I just have index problems but I think I know how to solve them. Thank you thank you thank you